# Should pip be installed with Windows Python 3 virtualenv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I am using Windows 7 and Python 3.3.3

I have created a virtual environment using:

```
PS> D:\Python33\python D:\Python33\Tools\Scripts\pyvenv.py my_new_python_env
```

I then activate the new environment using:

```
PS> .\my_new_python_env\Scripts\activate.ps1
```

I can check my python version and it says Python 3.3.3, all is good so far.

I was under the impression that I should have pip installed by default by pyvenv.py into the newly created virtual environment?  Is this true?
I do not see pip in the new environment, and I cannot run 'pip' after activating the new virtual environment.

NOTE: I'm specifically looking for the Windows answer to this question, TIA

**Update #1**
From the venv documentation here:
http://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

It appears that neither setuptools or pip are installed by venv.

**Update #2**
To install, I first downloaded setuptools from:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools

I activated my virtual environment, then ran:

```
> python setup.py install
```

This installed setuptools into the virtual environment

I then ran:

```
> easy_install pip
```

This downloaded and installed pip

Comment: I'm not certain what you mean by "pip installed by default."  If you mean it should come with the Python installation, it does not (but it will with Python 3.4!).  If this is virtualenv specific I can't help you at all, due to my gross incompetency with those.

Comment: @CodyPiersall, I meant installed in the newly created virtual enviroment.  I've updated my question to reflect this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the answer to the original question is: No, pip is not installed by Python 3 venv with Windows.

To install pip, I first downloaded setuptools from: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools

I activated my virtual environment,

I then changed to the downloaded setuptools directory and ran:

```
> python setup.py install
```

This installed setuptools into the virtual environment

I then ran:

```
> easy_install pip
```

This downloaded and installed pip